# When can I release my iOS 9.3 app?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have an iOS app that crashes with ios9.3 beta and will need to release it, can I just install Xcode 7.3 beta and release using the beta, or shall I wait until Xcode 7.3 is out of beta?

Comment: Unless something changed very recently, Apple won't let you release anything built with a beta version of Xcode.

Comment: lets travel with Apple :) even Apple would not allow to upload from xcode.

Comment: as soon as the full version of Xcode9.3 is released.

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit apps with Xcode 7.2 until a newer version is released.  Are you suggesting your app crashes on iOS 9.2?  If so, you should fix that, as not all users downloading from the app store will be on iOS 9.3 when it is released.

Comment: My app crashes with 9.3and has weird graphical glitches when UIPickerViews are involved. All is well with 9.2

Answer (score 0):

Here are few important points we my focus on:

- We cannot publish new App or update existing one from Beta Xcode version
- Most important thing is apple will not allow this
- Here the only case is you could wait for an Xcode 7.3 full version release

Hope it will he helpful for all.